Matrix derivative $\partial \text{tr} ( DXAPD + D P A^TX^T D )$ with respect to $X$
I want to compute
$\frac{ \partial \text{tr} ( DXAPD + D P A^TX^T D) } { \partial X}$. Here $D$ is an $n$ by $n$ diagonal matrix, $P$ is an $n$ by $n$ symmetric and positive definite matrix, $A$ is an $m$ by $n$  matrix and $X$ is $n$ by $m$.
I know that $\frac{ \partial \text{tr} ( XAP + PA^TX^T) } { \partial X} = 2(AP)^T$  But what happens if I multiply $D$ on both ends?

I would suggest you input this into this tool: https://www.matrixcalculus.org/matrixCalculus

Since $, \def\op{\operatorname} \op{tr}\left(M^T\right) = \op{tr}(M),$  you only need to differentiate one of the terms, then double it.

These calculations are usually easiest with the summation convention.
The basic fact is
$$
\frac{d}{dX} tr( D X E)_{l,m} = D_{i,j} \frac{d X_{j,k}}{dX_{l,m}} E_{ki} =D_{ij} \delta_{jl} \delta_{km} E_{ki} =D_{il} E_{mi} = (ED)_{ml} =(ED)^T_{lm} $$
And so
$$ \frac{d}{dX} tr(DXE)= D^T E^T$$
No assumptions about the form of D, E as long as the sizes work out. I am assuming that the components of X are all independent variables. Use linearity of trace to find any relation like this you want. In your case I get
$$
2 D^T (APD)^T = 2 D^2 P A^T
$$
Since $D$ and $P$ are symmetric.
